# Is there something that I can do in C but I can't do in C++?

Tags: c++, c

Is there something that I can do in C but I can't do in C++ ?
I stumbled upon the question in a sample interview questions site.

Comment: You can make Linus Torvald happy in C... beyond that, not really.

Comment: I think majority of the differences will be about syntax...

Comment: Is your question really about are there advantages to C over C++? If so then the answer is yes. For the details, either amend your question or ask another (actually this is probably on SO already).

Comment: I chekced for the similar question but couldn't see before I ask. Actually I was expecting things like litb's answer, but It seems different standarts came out and are being talked. Although I refered the latest versions, it is nice to hear about old ones.

Comment: How about: 'staying sane'?

Comment: But surely you can't do that in either?

Comment: Write code that _compiles_ fast

Comment: There's different possible meanings.  There's no computation you can accomplish in one language but not the other.  There are programs that will do one thing in C and something else in C++ (or fail to compile) according to the Standard, although rewriting these is usually trivial.  There are things that you can do in almost all common C implementations but not almost all common C++ implementations.

Comment: Nothing of significance. Older versions of C didn't have the level of compile-time type checking that C++ introduced (and later versions of C adopted), so there were some tricks you could do that were clever but not terribly useful beyond inspiring new rules in the IOCCC.

Comment: @happy_emi: that's a job for C# :P

Answer (score 54):

Declare a variable named 'class', as in:

```
int class = 0;
```

Comment: One of the best ways to ensure no one ever compiles your code on a `C++` compiler :D

Comment: Except that you can. The preprocessor is part of the language and there is no clause that you can not redefine a keyword with the pp.

Comment: @Luther: true the pp is part of the language specification. Nevertheless, if you use something like `#define class blah` and the above declaration, then your variable is *not* named `class`. It's named `blah`, since everything in the standard, including the names of things, is talking about what happens after macro replacement. Try it for something with external linkage...

Comment: @Luther:  Actually, if you include any standard library headers, it is prohibited to define as a macro an identifier that is lexically identical to a keyword.  So in any translation unit that includes a standard library header, `#define class blah` is invalid (off the top of my head, I don't know whether it renders the source ill-formed or just results in undefined behavior).

Comment: @James: #define class blah    #include "that_header.h"    #undef class

Comment: @Sjoerd:  _A translation unit that includes a header shall not contain any macros that define names declared or defined in that header.  Nor shall such a translation unit define macros for names lexically identical to keywords_  (C++03 §17.4.3.1.1).  Note that "a header" here specifically means "a standard library header."

Comment: @James: Thanks for the quote. It is clearly not allowed to #define class for a small part of our header. My expectation was that it was possible as long as the define would be undone at the point any standard library header was included; I was wrong.

Comment: This answer is funny, but misses the point (such funny commentary seems better suited as comments than as answers).  You can't use "int restrict = 0;" in C99, but you can in C++.  Whoopdedo.

Answer (score 22):

> ...that is there anything I can do in C but not in C++.

Both languages are Turing complete, so in theory you can code up equally functional applications in both.

OTOH, C++ is not a superset of C. Especially C99 has some features that C++ does not have. E.g. designated initializers, variable length arrays in structs and as automatic variables. Depending on your "anything", this could be something that C++ cannot do but C can.

Comment: If possible could you please give any simple program which do run in C and not C++

Comment: http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm shows quite a lot of examples of differences.

Comment: Many C99 features that aren't in C++ (yet) are already supported by many C++ compilers (especially compilers by vendors that have up to date C99 compilers).

Answer (score 19):

In C, you can create array literals ("compound literal"), but in C++ you cannot

```
/* p points to the first element of an array of 4 int */
int *p = (int[]){1, 2, 3, 4};
```

You can also create an array with size not yet known at compile time, but C++ has no such possibility ("variable length array"):

```
// create array. size is known at runtime only.
int p[rand() % 5 + 1];
```

Comment: What C complier lets you declare varaible length arrays?  When I try it, I get "error: expected constant expression"

Comment: At least VLAs are C99 - how well is it supported?

Comment: AShelly your compiler does not seem to support the last C standard (C99) in that regard. The feature was added after C++ has been standardized ('98)

Comment: C99 introduced variable sized arrays. gcc/g++ (4.2.3) supports it. In fact, unless g++ is specifically asked to be strict (-pedantic), it will work in C++ as well.

Comment: anyway, the interview asks about C . this is C , and the most recent version of it. statements such as "anything you can do in C you can do in C++." were never true. But since 1999, even less so, of course.

Comment: ... and i guess when you come up with differences that include c99, your employer will see you not only know old school, but modern C too. you can still provide it with c89 vs. c++03 difference (no tentative definitions, no default int, no implicit conversion from void* ...)

Comment: This compiler was MSVC++ 2005, using its defaults for .C files.  In this particular case (unlike many others), it actually agreeed with my expectations, which boil down to: 'if it's not in K&R 2nd Ed., it's not right'.  I admit it - I'm old school.

Comment: gcc does not support variable length arrays. They might appear to "work", but they are officially broken. See http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html

Comment: It might be worth just adding a note into your answer that you're explicitly referring to C99 and not C90.

Comment: i purposely don't mention C99 anywhere in my answer. most talk about C99 as a new language compared to C90, when in fact it "cancels and replaces" C90 (quoted from the draft). i will mention it in the answer, if the question is edited to "C90"/"C89" instead of just plain "C" indeed :)

Answer (score 10):

```
int new = 0;
```

works in C, but obviously can't work in C++ because 'new' is a reserved word.

There are some other 'tricks' with reserved words, but other than that, you can pretty much do everything in C that you can do in C++.

Comment: The question was not about the differences but about what C++ can't do what C can. It should be obvious that there are a lot of differences between the two.

Comment: Well then I'll rephrase on Darron's behalf: there are many more things which can be done in C but not C++, aside from just using C++ reserved symbols as names.

Comment: I undid my edit, which strengthened the concluding assertion; I did not realize that C99 had diverged C from being a subset of C++.

Answer (score 8):

C++ lacks C99's [`restrict` qualifier](https://web.archive.org/web/20090209061332/http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/cc_restrict.html).  Therefore, there is no way to tell the compiler to perform optimizations based around knowing that pointers aren't aliases.

Answer (score 7):

Quite  a few things. For example, in C you can write code like this:

```
void * v = 0;
char * p = v;
```

and you can create arrays like this:

```
int main() {
    int n = 42;
    int a[n];
    return 0;
}
```

neither of which will compile under C++.

Comment: In that last example, I think you might need C99 (or gcc).

Comment: @Neil: Well I agree with you, but I can imagine some people wouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

There are some things you can **say** in C wihch you can't in C++ (because C++ has stricter syntax-checking, and C has a more extensive 'legacy' syntax).

Also, there may be some run-time environments (O/S+library+compiler) which support C but not C++, so you can **do** C on those platforms where you can't do C++.

Answer (score 6):

Syntactically there are a few things you could write in C that wouldn't compile in C++ (See [Incompatibilities Between ISO C and ISO C++](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm) for excruciating details.).  If you're asking at a higher level, if there is some program that it's possible to write in C, but not possible to write in C++, then the answer is "No."

Comment: Doesn't seem to have affected the voting.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I can think of one example:

When you create a library (.lib file or .dll file) to be shared by other applications, you're better off using C instead of C++ because the results are more portable. You can do this within a C++ compiler by using an 'extern "C"' block though.

Specifically, C++ has a quirk where there is no standard convention for name mangling - for translating your library's function signatures into more low level names used by the compiler. So for example if you have a function like 'int addNumbers (int a, int b)', different C++ compilers may translate this function into different names, which can lead to problems when you want to import the library. If you use a C compiler or surround your library importing and exporting code with a C block though you won't see this problem, since there is only one way to mangle function names in C.

Comment: Actually, C does not specify a standard ABI.

Comment: This is why extern "C" exists.

Comment: C does not specify any ABI, but is simple enough that everybody agreed to use the same ABI. Unlike C++.

Answer (score 4):

In 'C' you don't need forward declarations.  This allows you to pass parameters which are interpreted incorrectly.  *(Not that this is a great feature, but you can't do it in C++)*

in file A:

```
float sum(float a, float b)
{
   return a+b;
}
```

in file B

```
main()
{
  printf("%f\n", sum(1,2));
}
```

with C, this compiles, but prints 0.000

with C++, you need a `float sum(float,float);` before the printf, and it gives the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

You can sparsely initialize arrays in C. I like to use it for mapping int->sometype for relatively dense static maps where an unmapped value can be interpreted as 0:

```
int my_array[] = { [1] = 3, [4] = 2 };
printf("%d %d %d\n", sizeof my_array, my_array[0], my_array[1]);
/* prints 20, 0, 3 */
```

Comment: @Matt Havener: This works in C++ too for me! At least on some variants, used clang in xcode.

Comment: This feature is called designated initializers and is a cool C99 feature. Trying it with clang, for C++, it compiles but with a warning saying that this is C99 feature not not supported by C++.

Answer (score 4):

The 1998 C++ standard has a list of incompatibilities with the 1990 C standard that is 13 pages long (Annex C). Granted, it's not a lot, compared to the amount of pages that describe the languages, but still covers quit a bit of ground.

Quick summary of the kind of differences that it lists:

- New keywords are added (any C program that uses them as identifiers is not C++)
- Type of character literal changed from int to char (compare `sizeof('a')` in C and C++!)
- String literals made const (can't do `char* q = expr ? "abc" : "de";`)
- "Tentative definitions" are removed from the language.
- "Compatible types" are removed from the language.
- Converting from void* to any other pointer now requires casting.
- Converting from any const/volatile pointer to void* now requires casting.
- "Implicit declarations" are removed from the language.
- Expressions can no longer create new types (as in `p = (void*)(struct x {int i;} *)0;` )
- results of some expressions became lvalues (compare `sizeof(0, arr)` for `char arr[100];`)

...that was the first 3 pages of Annex C.

If you go to the 1999 C standard, the differences are going to take forever to describe. Although C++0x did include some of C99 features, many of them are just inherently incompatible, like the complex type.

Answer (score 4):

In C, you can declare variables with the following names:

```
bool, class, new, delete, template, typename, this, throw, catch, 
typeid, operator, virtual, static_cast, reinterpret_cast, 
dynamic_cast, mutable, public, private, protected, friend; //many more
```

then you can do these:

```
int namespace = private + protected + public;
int decltype  = static_cast + dynamic_cast + reinterpret_cast;
int constexpr = (new + delete) * (template + typename);
```

All of them are keywords in C++11.

Comment: I can just imagine the chaos if I tried compiling that with G++ lol

Answer (score 2):

You can do almost everything in any of the programming languages. Of course the way of expressing it will vary, as well as the amount of code, clarity of code, ease of further maintenance. Some tasks can be coded with few lines in Prolog and few pages of code in C++, and so on.

Some limiting factors are the available libraries, available compilers, and low-level issues. However when you consider C and C++ on a typical PC, then there is no difference in things that can be done in either of them.

Unless of course you were asking for the differences between C and C++ - for these other people have given you the idea.

Comment: "You can do almost everything in any of the programming languages." is good point actually.

Comment: Church-Turing Thesis, and all that.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *c = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

is valid in C, not C++ i.e. automatically casting `void*`. This of course is a syntax issue, not so much as what you can and cannot _do_ (i.e. accomplish).

Answer (score 2):

If the criteria is to solve a particular programming problem then both will do the job although it may be a bit easier in some cases to do it in C++ due to the higher level of abstraction

Comment: "... although it may be a bit easier in some cases to do it in C due to the lower level of complexity". There. Fixed it for ya'. :)

Comment: Well if you are into print hello programs I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Many aspects of hardware-related embedded ("freestanding") systems programming are only possible in C.

- [Major difference] In C you can do `union` type punning, which is done is pretty much every professional microcontroller hardware peripheral register map ever written. This is undefined behavior in C++.
- In C you can use the de facto standard freestanding implementation-defined form of main() as `void main (void)`. This is not allowed in C++ because of artificial restrictions. You must either have your bare metal C++ program return a value to la-la-land or name the procedure entered at startup something else than `main`.
- When using structs allocated with static storage duration in C, you can have them quickly initialized with just a "zero out" (.bss initialization). Doing the same in C++ with structs/classes will mean that member variables get "zeroed out" too, but in addition default constructors will get called, leading to needlessly slow program startup.
- [Major difference] In C you can declare `const` variables without initializing them. This is very useful for `const volatile` variables declared in EEPROM/flash, to be written to in run-time by bootloaders and similar. In C++ you are forced to initialize the variables, which in turn forces default values to get burned into EEPROM/flash, leading to slower programming time and slightly more physical memory wear.
- [Major difference] No standard library function in C performs heap allocation silently/implicitly, apart from the `malloc` family (and in C23, `strdup` as well). In C++, silent heap allocation is very common in standard library functions, making those libraries unsuitable for embedded systems.
- `restrict` pointers are possible to use in C for various micro-optimizations.
- C allows pointers to VLA, which can help improving readability and diagnostics. On the other hand, C++ doesn't allow objects of VLA type, which is a good thing in embedded systems. C compilers can optionally refuse to implement certain aspects of VLA depending on their standard compliance (C99 vs C11/C17 vs C23 - C23 being the most suitable for embedded systems in regards of VLA).
- C++ didn't support designated initializers until C++20 and these are quite handy to have in all manner of situations. (C++ does support initializer lists with named members inside constructors, however.)
- C doesn't allow exception handling and I'd say that's a huge benefit in embedded systems. You'll want to avoid opening that can of worms inside your deterministic firmware. Error handling in C is rather handled gracefully by returning an error code from one module to its caller and then further down the line as needed. Instead of violently crashing down the dependency chain if left unhandled, just like the average run-away code bug would. It is however possible to write exception-free code in C++ too, if done with great care.
- [Major difference] "Forever loops" is an important concept in programming, particularly so in embedded systems programming, where even empty loops with no side effects are common. And yet C++ doesn't support that. [Optimizing away a "while(1);" in C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x). A perfectly valid embedded systems program might look like `init_interrupts(); for(;;){}`. However, the C++ committee have apparently not taken such very common scenarios in consideration, so you can't write such programs in C++.

Benefits of C++ over C in hardware-related programming:

- Inline assembler is standardized in C++, since C++ predicted that the programs written in it would get executed on computers. C did make no such prediction and so inline assembler/running your C program on a computer is not yet supported even in C23. It's just sad. (Similarly sad, neither language has a standardized interrupt keyword.)
- C++ historically has a much better system for static assertions than C, which didn't support them proper until C11 (and further support is added in C23).
- C++ guarantees a diagnostic message when doing implicit pointer conversions to/from `void*`. C does not. And `void` pointers are generally to be avoided in embedded systems.
- You cannot call main() recursively in C++.
- Conditional expressions with logic/relational/equality operators in C++ result in `bool`.
- Character constants (`'A'`) are of type `char` in C++, which saves a tiny bit of memory.

Comment: Some of the issues are purely theoretical. `restrict` can be replaced with `__restrict`. Union type punning is explicitly allowed at least in GCC manual.

Answer (score 1):

Is this referring to the latest C standard?  The original C standard (ANSI 1989 or ISO 1990, with 1995 updates) is fairly close to being a subset of C++.  There's differences, but they're mostly contrived (the biggest exception probably being that void * converts freely with any data pointer in C but not in C++).

However, a [new C standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) came out in 1999, some time after I'd stopped doing anything in the most modern C.  It had new features, some of which are going into the C++ standard due this year or next, but not all.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not support named struct member initialization but in C you can do:

```
struct { int x, y; } a = { .x = 3 };
```

You can also combine this with the feature shown by [Matt Havener](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62723/matt-havener):

```
struct { int a[3], b; } w[] = { [0].a = {1}, [1].a[0] = 2 };
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ is obviously not a superset of C for a very simple reason: New keywords have been added to C++
class, virtual, new, etc and thus can no more be used as identifiers in C++.

Some of the reasons are subtler.
You can find an exhaustive answer to this question on Bjarn Stroustrup's website:
[The C++ programming language | Appendix B](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_compat.pdf)

Comment: Your comment misses the point but I really liked your link on Bjarn Stroustrup's site, which highlights subtle C/C++ differences in great detail.

Answer (score 1):

C can have a function with an unspecified amount of arguments. Disclaimer that this is bad practice and shouldn't be used, but present and interesting nonetheless:

```
void x() { }
```

in C means a function with an unspecified amount of parameters. This is as opposed to

```
void x(void) { }
```

Which means a function with **0** parameters in C. In C++ both functions mean the same thing and take 0 arguments.

Using the unspecified parameter count in C, you could access the parameters the same way you would using variable arguments.

So:

```
void x()
{

}

int main()
{
    // This line would compile in C and C++
    x();

    // This line compiles in C but not C++
    x(5, 7)

    return 0;
}
```

That is why you should try to write `void` as a parameter instead of leaving them blank. In C always explicitly write `void` so you don't have issues, and inC++ both are equivalent so it doesn't matter but it's nice to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

"If it can't be done in assembly, it's not worth doing!"

ok, humor aside, I *THINK* the OP is asking syntactically, rather than operationally.

I think that there are a few obscure things that are legal in C (at least C89) that are not legal in C++, or at least deprecated... But (if they exist) they're pretty obscure. C++ is functionally a superset of C.

Comment: Good point. Really the only difference is syntactical. If there were an operational advantage (on top of the existing syntactical advantage) to C over C++ compilers, I'd be extremely interested.

Comment: Well, C++ compilers' name mangling is not inter-operable in the way that C compilers' is. Linking multiple C libraries built with different compilers is doable. Linking multiple C++ libraries built with different compilers: not so much.

Comment: I mentioned two operational advantages in my answers - creating portable libraries and writing programs for a platform that only has a C compiler. Though I can't think of a concrete example for the latter.

Comment: "C++ is functionally a superset of C." It never was. And since this answer was posted, C++ (11 and beyond) has gone completely haywire in relation to C.

Comment: @Lundin: Unfortunately, neither the C nor C++ Committee is willing to recognize a principle that should be self-evident: if striking part of the Standard that exists for the purpose of optimization would make it possible to perform via defined means an action that facilitates some tasks, then unless there is some other equally-good way of performing those tasks, that part of the Standard makes the language worse for those tasks than it otherwise would be.  Doing that to facilitate optimizing transforms that would be irrelevant for many tasks is a "root-of-all-evil" premature optimization.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is...no, not really. See http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#difference