# Is there anything that i can do in C but not in C++?

Tags: c++, c, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there something that I can do in C but I can’t do in C++ ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513009/is-there-something-that-i-can-do-in-c-but-i-cant-do-in-c)

I am in a graduate level and I seen that C++ is derived from C with OOP added. I have a doubt that is there anything I can do in C but not in C++.