# Why is this output waiting for something after it?

Tags: c++, delay, wait, clock, cout

```
void Wait(double Duration)
{
    clock_t End;
    End = clock() + (Duration*CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    while (clock() < End)
    {
        // This loop just stalls the program.
    }
}
```

My function works perfectly half the time, but it occasionally stalls the program before it's even called.  For example, take the following snippet:

```
cout << "This is\n";
Wait(2.5)
cout << "a test!";
```

You'd expect the first line to appear immediately and the second line to appear after 2.5 seconds, but it sometimes ALL appears after 2.5 seconds.  What's the deal?

Comment: There is almost certainly a better way to do what you really want to do.  Let us know your platform/compiler, and we can give better advice.

Comment: Does this only happen for you with a cout? Keep in mind that it's buffered. So if you don't flush, I think you might get the behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct, but is it possible the compiler is optimizing away the loop as it doesn't appear to do anything?  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x

Comment: Be carefull with the information you are giving away. They will first ask for the platform/compiler, then your address. Finally you may end up with a bunch of programmers in your kitchen trying help you with your beer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
cout.flush();
```

before your Wait

Answer (score 4):

That might be because of I/O buffering.
You should flush the output buffer (either try `<< endl` instead of `'\n'` or writing `cout.flush`) manually.

Answer (score 2):

Try `cout << "This is" << endl;`

It looks like a buffering, not clock issue.

Answer (score 2):

The flush()/std::endl has already been mentioned - but is your intention to really consume 100% of one core while you wait? This is what the `while()` loop is doing! If you want a nicer approach to "waiting", consider one of the following:

1. boost::thread::sleep() - millisecond granularity
2. alarms (1 second granularity)
3. select()
4. pthread_cond_timedwait()

etc.