# Python wait for x seconds without sleeping program?

Tags: python

I want to make my program wait for `x` seconds after an if statement is triggered but I don't want my whole program to sleep cause I still want it to work.

So `time.sleep` is out of the question, what options are there?

Comment: Does a [busy loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911397/what-is-a-busy-loop) work for you?

Comment: If you're using asynchronous code, look into [`asyncio.sleep(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping)

Comment: There's many threads on SO regarding this topic. Pick whatever solution you feel works for you. But essentially, your key words you're looking for is "python run multiple functions in parallel". Best of luck on your project that we have no information on because you didn't give us any code :)