# Decrease varibale until a condition is met (in bodyless while loop )

Tags: c, while-loop

I am looking for something like this:

```
int nVal = 130;
while(nVal % 6 != 0)
  nVal--;
```

in a while loop without body:

```
int nVal = 130;
while(nVal-- % 6 != 0)
```

Of course that way, the `--` operator is called once too often.
Any suggestions here or should I go with option #1?

Comment: `while(--nVal % 6 != 0)`.. But why? There's  nothing wrong with a `while`-body.

Comment: Why do you need a bodyless `while`? Concentrate on writing clean code and let the compiler do optimisations like this one..

Comment: This code is equivalent to `nVal=126`. And it what would be produced by a good compiler.

Answer (score 5):

Use the first alternative as it is clearer and correct. It is never a good idea to show as many operators as possible into a single line. Particularly not the `++` and `--` operators since those include a side effect, and are therefore notoriously dangerous to use together with other operators.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this: `while((nVal-- -1) % 6 != 0)`
but, as Lundin said, the first example is clearer

Comment: It sure is, but @tzippy wanted to have a bodyless while loop, so I provided

Answer (score 0):

After the optimization it should be the same code in asm.
Probably it could be better to use --nVal instead of nVal-- but with -o3 it does not matter I think.

Comment: I don't think the optimizer would be allowed to produce the same assembly for prefix/postfix in this case because they aren't semantically identical

Comment: 2nd option decreases the value even when the condition evaluates to 0, so they are not equivalent.

Comment: If the optimizer is smart enough it will be reduced to `nVal=126`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Are loop bodies evaluated during optimization? I thought that this kind of thing normally wouldn't be done because in the majority of cases the code cannot be evaluated at compile time

Comment: @awksp You can't know for sure. Optimizers are getting better (worse?) in this type of things. They can even do strange things like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262801/what-is-my-best-approach-to-determining-compiler-behaviour-for-empty-infinite-lo).

Comment: I've looked at the asm code after Visual studio (don't remember version) there where too loops with ++i and i++ and optimized code were the same in both cases.