# Thread inside a class with member function from another class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Can someone tell me how can I run a new thread with member function from a object of diffrent class as a member function of this class ? What ever im trying to do Im still getting errors.

> `no match for call to '(std::thread) (void (Boo::*)(), Boo&)'|`
>   `no match for call to '(std::thread) (void (Foo::*)(), Foo*)'|`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
class Boo
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        while(1){}
    }
};

class Foo
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        t1(&Boo::run,boo);
        t2(&Foo::user,this);
    }
    void user();
    ~Foo(){
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
private:
    std::thread t1;
    std::thread t2;
    Boo boo;
};
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.run();
}
```

Comment: `while(1){}` is UB, see for example [is-this-infinite-recursion-ub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905155/is-this-infinite-recursion-ub).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `operator=` to **assign** the threads after construction

Working example below ([see it in action](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eddaad508114c72d)):

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class Boo
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        int i = 10;
        while(i--)
        {
            std::cout << "boo\n";;
        }
    }
};

class Foo
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        t1 = std::thread(&Boo::run,boo);   // threads already default constructed
        t2 = std::thread(&Foo::user,this); // so need to *assign* them 
    }

    void user()
    {
        int i = 10;
        while(i--)
        {
            std::cout << "foo\n";;
        }
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }

private:
    std::thread t1;
    std::thread t2;
    Boo boo;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.run();
}
```

Comment: His errors are because the run() and user() methods the threads call do not accept parameters, would your code not still have these errors?

Comment: No, you're mistaken - the call he's trying to make is to execute the `run` **member function** of `Boo`, using the object `boo`. That is, you need both a member function pointer and an object instance

Comment: Ok thanks, I misremembered the second parameter of the thread constructor. Deleted my incorrect answer