# Round robin algorithm in a loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, round-robin

How round-robin algorithm can be implemented that runs in a loop for ever?

```
for (int i = 0; ;i++){
    roundRobinIndex = i % numberOfWorkers;
}
```

The problems with the way above is that `integer overflow` problem. It can also be implemented with checking the value of `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; ;i++){
    roundRobinIndex = i % numberOfWorkers;
    if i == maxNumber{
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

But this way seems ugly. Maybe there is more elegant way?

Comment: Please put in the OP tags the target language.

Comment: "ugly" is a very subjective notion :) what's ugly here, to me, is that we're using a modulo call, which is expensive.

Comment: @OlivierSohn What do you replace the `%` operation with?  In the past I have tried various tricks to avoid the "expensive" call but nothing I did was better for variable inputs.  To be clear, not trolling looking to learn.

Comment: @Matt Don't worry about these micro-optimizations unless you can prove that they matter. This is premature optimization, and it is may be that your compiler generates better code for modulo than you could come up with yourself (e.g. if the number of workers is a compile time constant).

Comment: @Matt did you see my answer? I don't use modulo in it

Comment: Do you need both the `i` and `roundRobinIndex` variables or just the latter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not ?

```
int numberOfWorkers = 10
int roundRobinIndex = numberOfWorkers - 1
while(true){
    roundRobinIndex = (roundRobinIndex + 1) % numberOfWorkers
}
```

or with a for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; ;i = (i + 1) % numberOfWorkers){
    roundRobinIndex = i;
}
```

We can now get rid of `i`

Comment: It may be premature optimization, but you can also just write `i++; if (i == numberOfWorkers) i = 0;` or some variation. Most compilers will likely do this transformation for you instead of a more costly modulus operation but it's just as short.

Comment: Indeed, it depend on what we aim to do, I suspected OP wanted some elegant code, not the most effective

Comment: BTW, [the infinite loop is UB without "visible" effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905171/2684539).

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding any modulo call, we can do:

```
constexpr int nextRR(int curIdx, int sz) {
    if(curIdx==sz-1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return curIdx+1;
}

for (int rrIndex = 0;;rrIndex = nextRR(rrIndex, sz)) {
    // use rrIndex here ...

}
```

This will be performance-wise more effective than any modulo-based solution, if the number of workers is not known at compile time.

Note that `nextRR` can also be written like this, to optimize even further for platforms where comparison with 0 is faster than a comparison with a variable:

```
constexpr int nextRR(int curIdx, int sz) {        
    if(curIdx==0) {
        return sz-1;
    }
    return curIdx-1;
}
```

Comment: This is 1. rejected in the question itself and 2. not guaranteed to be faster (even ignoring the fact that your compiler will probably optimize all the mentioned solutions to the same machine code).

Comment: @MaxLanghof please show me a compiler that does that :) and I disagree with you first point too, as said in the comment : "ugly" is a subjective notion...

Comment: For example, if your max index is a compile time constant, your compiler may replace the modulo by something much faster (like `and` for powers of two) which can easily beat branching (or conditional moves). See [here](https://godbolt.org/g/sQMbeF). I couldn't immediately get it to transform both into the same, but your universal performance claim is simply false.

Comment: @MaxLanghof yes,  "if" it is a compile time constant. But it's not the case here...

Comment: I dislike the name you gave to your function and variables, but I agree: an `if(overflow) { reset; }`is easier to read (you get it at first glance) than modulo arithmetic. Finally, I don't care about performance at that level except if I did a profile first. +1 anyway

Comment: @YSC I changed the variable name, hope you like it better :) I profiled similar alternatives on an earlier project and saw that the non-modulo option was faster

Comment: @OlivierSohn It is unspecified whether this is a compile-time constant, which means your statement is not generally true. I've also seen modulo transformed into simple conditional code (for constant modulus) in my own code.

Comment: @MaxLanghof it's not specified in the question that it's a constant. But I agree with you, compilers do smart things when they have info a compile time.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I'm glad you like it now :)

Comment: Why are you checking `curIdx==sz-1` instead of, say `return curIdx < sx ? curIdx + 1 : 0;`?

Comment: @Bob__ Because your condition is incorrect. If `curIdx` is not smaller than `sx`, you are already out of range. You either need to increment beforehand (see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51211812/9528746)) or twice if you don't want the check with `-1`. Or do something unreadable like `++curIdx < sx ? curIdx : 0`.

Comment: @Bob__ I agree that testing using an inequality may be more robust, in case `sz` changes. Then it would be `return curIdx < sz-1 ? curIdx+1 : 0`.

Comment: @Bob__: [Your code](https://godbolt.org/g/MQgU5g) is UB btw. infinite loop without needed operation.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think you meant to comment on an other answer, as the code in the link and my code don't match. Can you move your comment please?

Comment: @OlivierSohn: code matches (first) comment of Bob (that's why I notified Bob and not you).

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah, since C++11, right? The point was showing that compilers can make drastic choices and OP's code hasn't side effects too.

Comment: @Bob__: I think it is worded differently before but with same effect.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness (I agree that pLopeGG's answer is more elegant) - your way would work perfectly well if you make `i` an `unsigned int` rather than `int` since the overflow is defined in the standard for unsigned overflows, but not signed.

ie

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; ;i++){
    roundRobinIndex = i % numberOfWorkers;
}
```

Comment: This is (in theory) problematic if your number of workers is not a power of two. Note that this is the [same reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator) why you may get bias with mapping a random integer into your desired range.

Comment: @MaxLanghof an error of 1 every 4,294,967,295 isn't a strong enough bais to be worth worrying about.

Comment: If the code depends on round-robin indices actually proceeding in round-robin fashion and not restarting from 0 randomly, it very much is worth worrying about.

Comment: @MaxLanghof don't disagree - I also don't think OP cares since they suggest that algorithm in the question - which is why I posted the version that didn't result in UB.

Answer (score -1):

Why not put the `%` into the loop?

```
for (int i = 0; ;++i, i %= numberOfWorkers)
{
}
```

Comment: ...why not just `i = (i+1) % numberOfWorkers`?

Comment: Nobody likes that poor, lonely coma operator :(