# Prevent C++11 removal of endless loops

Tags: c++, c++11, embedded

As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x), C++11 optimizes endless loops away.

However, in embedded devices which have a single purpose, endless loops make sense and are actually quite often used. Even a completely empty `while(1);` is useful for a watchdog-assisted reset. Terminating but empty loops can also be useful in embedded development.

Is there an elegant way to specifically tell the compiler to not remove empty or endless loops, without disabling optimization altogether?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the requirements for a loop to be removed (as mentioned in that question) is that it

> - does not access or modify volatile objects

So,

```
void wait_forever(void)
{
    volatile int i = 1;
    while (i) ;
}
```

*should* do the trick, although I would certainly verify this by looking at the disassembly of a program produced with your particular toolchain.

A function like this would be a good candidate for GCC's [`noreturn`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-functions-that-never-return-3115) attribute as well.

```
void wait_forever(void) __attribute__ ((noreturn));

void wait_forever(void)
{
    volatile int i = 1;
    while (i) ;
}

int main(void)
{
    if (something_bad_happened)
        wait_forever();
}
```

Comment: Does `wait_forever()` still have to read the volatile `i` if it has the `noreturn` attribute? If yes, then what problem does this attribute solve?

Comment: As mentioned in the linked-to GCC documentation, `noreturn` tells the compiler that execution cannot possibly ever continue after calling a `noreturn` function.  Therefore, it doesn't have to emit *any* code after a call to such a function.