# Why is a `fork()` call not optimized away in an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, fork, posix

Considering

*C++11 §1.10/24 (in [intro.multithread])*

> **”** The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one of the following:
>   — terminate,
>   — make a call to a library I/O function,
>   — access or modify a volatile object, or
>   — perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation.
>   [Note: This is intended to allow compiler transformations such as removal of empty loops, even when
>   termination cannot be proven. —end note ]

… is the compiler allowed to optimize away the following loop:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    while ( true )
        fork();
}
```

?

(There is some earlier discussion at ([Optimizing away a "while(1);" in C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x)), but it does not seem to answer the case of a `fork` call in the loop.)

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Reverting good edits is frowned upon. If the edit makes the question better, leave it; don't fight over it. If the OP believes it's a bad edit, they'll let us know and revert. Also, if you're interested in discussing this, [we have a meta post for that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288802/).

Comment: The [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288802/) mentions that this is a *fork bomb*. Running this program can cause your system to hang.

Comment: This question does not seem too broad to me. It essentially asks whether The compiler must assume a call to an `extern` function does one of those 4 things, which is a yes/no answer.

Answer (score 10):

`fork` is a normal function just like other library functions it invokes `glibc fork()` wrapper rather than invoking system call directly.

A compiler has no way to determine what does this function contain and a conformant compiler should always avoid optimizing this loop away and this would result in [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) as referred in one of the comment.

To avoid the consequences, one should avoid the maximum number of processes a user can own.

From man fork

> Since  version  2.3.3,  rather than invoking the kernel's fork() system call, the glibc fork() wrapper that is provided as part
>   of the NPTL threading implementation invokes clone(2) with flags
>   that provide the same effect as the traditional system call.  The glibc wrapper invokes any fork handlers that have been established
>   using pthread_atfork(3).

Comment: A compiler may optimize calls to functions defined by the C or C++ standard library, as long as the optimizing code behaves the same way. For example, gcc can and will optimize `printf("hello\n")` to `puts("hello")`. `fork()` is defined by POSIX, not by the language standard -- but I'd say that a POSIX-conforming implementation can legally optimize a call to `fork` as long as the resulting code still behaves as specified by POSIX and by the language standard. Whether that applies in this specific case is an interesting question (and I don't have an answer).

Comment: @Mohit: Which of the bullets in the quoted C++ standard text is satisfied by the call to `fork()`? I don't find your answer compelling or convincing, I'm afraid!

Comment: @KeithThompson Lightness: Thanks for the valuable comments. When I said **conformant** in my answer my intention was `C++ conformant`. Pre C++11 compilers for sure can not optimize this away. C++11 conformant (not with posix extensions) would see fork as a library call and it can not be optimized away as the observable behavior of this function is unknown to the compiler. All posix suggests is, on invocation of `fork` call, a new process is created which is an exact copy of calling process(immediately/deferred etc not mentioned). If the process does nothing, not creating it may not hurt posix.

Comment: I don't think that means it cannot optimise the call away. I think it means it can assume the call abides by the four bullet points.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit A non-posix compliant compiler has no way to ensure that fork call doesn't abide the bullet points. (For ex: it doesn't make a call to library IO function) Isn't it?

Comment: @MohitJain: It doesn't need to "ensure" it. It is allowed to assume. I concede that, in practice, implementations almost certainly _don't_ assume, for the reason you give. But this is about what the standard allows, not about what actually happens. Real-life constraints are always going to be _at least_ as strict as the standard requirements... "at least" being the key phrase!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Wow. Thanks for your comment and rectifying my interpretation. This is disturbing, as it allows compilers to eliminate following code `for(;/*ever*/;) checkAndForwardBluetoothQueue();`  assuming `checkAndForwardBluetoothQueue` is in a different compilation unit and where it waits for a condition variable (Bullet 4) for finite time, reads/writes a chip buffer using register (Bullet 3) and updates some logs (Bullet 2) and terminates (Bullet 1) if disconnect command is received.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Wait, what? The compiler can eliminate useful I/O code from an infinite loop? Are you sure that's what you mean?!

Comment: @MohitJain: No, the compiler *can't* eliminate your `for` loop with `checkAndForwardBluetoothQueue`. The standard says that the compiler may assume that the thread will eventually do one of the four things. Since it has no knowledge of what `checkAndForwardBluetoothQueue` does, it has no way to determine whether or not the function does any of those four things - so it must assume that it does.

Comment: @psmears: That is neither what I mean nor what I said.