# Unexpected behaviour of std::cout

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I was playing around with function pointers recently, when I discovered that the value of the function pointer as printed by `std::cout` always evaluates to 1.

However that was not the case with `printf()`, and it prints the expected result.

It'd be great if someone could explain the reason behind such behavior.
Below is the code sample for reference.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int  fun(int a)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{

    cout<<(&fun)<<endl; //always prints 1
    printf("%u",&fun); //this prints the expected result

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: g++: _warning: the address of 'int fun(int)' will always evaluate as 'true'_

Comment: It looks like `cout` don't know type of pointer to your function, and transform it to `boolean`

Comment: Also, `"%u"` is not the correct `printf()` format specifier for an address and is thus undefined behavior.  The correct format specifier for a `void *` is `%p`, so you have to cast to `void *`.

Comment: If you are using printf, you might want to include the proper header

Comment: Which compiler `cout` prints `1`? Try the very code on other Compilers and you'll get a different results. I guess it's a UB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `printf` call is simply undefined behavior. A function pointer is not an unsigned integer, and thus supplying it for a `%u` argument is not valid. (Try running this code on a 64-bit platform. You won't get the correct function pointer value.)

The `cout` on the other hand is type-safe. The compiler sees a function pointer argument and tries to find the best printing function (`operator<<` overload) it can. There is no such overload for function pointers themselves and the pointers don't offer a lot of implicit conversions. There is just one overload that works, and that is the one for `bool`. So the compiler converts the non-`NULL` function pointer to `true` and passes that. The overload then prints this as `1`, but you could use the `std::boolalpha` modifier to make it print as `true` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cout` treats `(&fun)` as a boolean expression and warns that it will always evaluate to `true` (i.e. non-zero).

Try casting it to `void*` as addresses should be printed, and check what happens:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int  fun(int a){
    return 0;
}

int main(){

    cout<<(void*)(&fun)<<endl; //always prints 1

    /* Side note: This will print the same as above */
    // cout<<(void*)(fun)<<endl;  // note the missing &

    printf("%p",(void*)&fun); //this prints the expected result
    // while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

output on mu machine:

```
0x401460
0x401460
```

Comment: Why have you got `while(1);`?

Comment: I use it to ensure the cmd window is not closed when I open it for execution

Comment: It should be responsibility of your enviroment, not your program. Strictly speaking, infinite loops like this are UB.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot didn't know that, thx! BTW, I use a batch script that compiles my code and executes it, thus I use the _while(1);_ as a fix. what would be a better way?

Comment: `pause` command in the batch file, for example.

Comment: How is an In finite loop ub?

Comment: _Note that it means that a program with endless recursion or endless loop (whether implemented as a for-statement or by looping goto or otherwise) has undefined behavior._ from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320725/is-infinite-loop-still-undefined-behavior-in-c-if-it-calls-shared-library

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I don't think they're UB, but they definitely can be optimized out.

Comment: Perhaps read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio

Comment: some of the solutions there suggest `getchar()` which is not very far from `while(1)` IMO. I eventually changed my batch call to `start /wait "C:...`