# i want to know How many times will this loop execute

Tags: c++

#### How many times will this loop execute?

```
unsigned char half_limit = 150;

for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 2 * half_limit; ++i)
 {
  // do something;
 }
```

Comment: `std::cout << i << std::endl` ?

Comment: run the code and count the times....

Comment: Your teacher wants to check your understanding of integer types, not ours.

Comment: 2*150 cannot be stored in a single unsigned char, your loop control variable overflows. Infinite loop.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: You miss integer promotion.

Comment: 0 - the compiler will optimise it away

Comment: @Jarod42 No. I said that `i` will never reach 2*150...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Being half way on your side, solely, *"2*150 cannot be stored in a single unsigned char"* is unprecise, giving the impression we were calculating in unsigned char - which would overflow as well...

Comment: My answer would be: _"It very much depends on what `// do something;` does."_

Answer (score 4):

Transforming the comments into appropriate answer:

`2*half_limit` results in `300` due to [integer promotion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/integer-promotions-in-c/) (link is for C, but same rules apply for C++), however, this value cannot be stored in `unsigned char` (`i`!!!), which means that the loop variable never can reach it; instead, it will overflow when being 255 at `++i` and thus "restarts" with 0.

The result is an infinite loop (assuming the `do something` part does not modify half_limit).

Side note 1: This applies for most common and ancient hardware, as these typically have eight bit wide char types. However, C++ standard's only (and just the same in C...) requirement for unsigned char is being able to minimally hold the values from 0 to 255 (and actually, not having larger size than unsigned short). Signed and unsigned char being larger than 8 bit is absolutely valid, and such hardware even exists (e. g. some DSP from TI with 16-bit char). On *such* hardware, the loop would have run 300 times!

Side note 2: If there are no visible side effects in the `do something` part, the compiler is allowed to optimise the loop away entirely, so it might not be run at all; however, we have undefined behaviour in the endless loop case (refer to Jarod's[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49529638/1312382))!

*Conclustion:* As long as we do not know the hardware we are running on, what the `do something` part really contains and which compiler was used with which optimisation flags, we actually cannot tell anything at all...

Comment: The *minimum requirement* of the standard is that `unsigned char` represent the range `0` to `255`.     That is common in practice, but an implementation is permitted to provide an `unsigned char` with a larger range.

Comment: @Peter Sure, already worked on architectures with CHAR_BIT == 16... But if it were the case in given situation, we would not have ended up in endless loop (not even with CHAR_BIT == 9)...

Comment: The loop does not loop because the optimizer removes the whole loop because it does nothing.

Comment: @user743414 Actually, if the `do something` really just is a comment, we have undefined behaviour, so *anything* could happen... Just removing the loop only is the most likely outcome. Actually, the compiler is not forced to optimise the loop away either - consider -O0 flags (GCC/clang)...

Answer (score 0):

in `i < 2 * half_limit`, we have integer promotion: we compare so `i` with `300`.

`i`, as `unsigned char` would never reach that limit.

Overflow of `unsigned char` is well defined, and wrap around maximum value.

So the loop in infinite.

So unless `// do something;` does any of:

- makes calls to library I/O functions
- does access or modify volatile objects
- or performs synchronization operations or atomic operations

the code would be Undefined Behavior (UB)

Comment: @Peter: See for example [is-infinite-loop-still-undefined-behavior-in-c-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320725/is-infinite-loop-still-undefined-behavior-in-c-if-it-calls-shared-library)

Comment: `// do something;` can also modify `half_limit`.

Comment: @DanielLangr: Indeed, we all assume that `half_limit` wasn't modified. Else with with `half_limit = 0;`, there is only one iteration :-)