# Why does the memory leak program not crash(killed by oom_killer)?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

- I write a typical program with memory leak and I want to test whether it will be killed by oom_killer.

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

constexpr size_t kBytes = 1 << 30;  // 1G bytes

int main () {
  std::cout << kBytes << std::endl;
  int cnt = 0;
  while (true) {
    char* p = static_cast<char*>(malloc(kBytes));
    std::cout << ++cnt << "," << "addr of p is :" << p << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But, the program is not crashed and it seems to be blocked.

- The last iteration value of cnt is 131063.
- The memory consumption is not growing anymore.

[The output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghcAU.png)

[The result of the top command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGIBW.png)

It's a very typical program with memory leak, but I don't know why it didn't crashed.

Comment: Your `malloc` calls are probably failing early on, if not immediately. 1 GiB is a lot of sequential memory to request. Program has undefined behavior, treating `p` as an initialized null-terminated string. It is not. It could be NULL, and the string is never initialized. If you want to output the address, cast it to a `void*`.

Comment: Note that gigabyte-size leaks are not a _"very typical program with memory leak"_. Leaks are more typically on the order of many blocks that range in size from a few bytes to a few kilobytes.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in a C++ program? Surely `new` is better.

Comment: You may wish to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320725/

Comment: Just by having an infinite loop, you're in undefined behavior territory.

Comment: Note that with a modern CPU odds are very good that if you don't actually use the memory, you don't actually get the memory. It checks "Is this allocation possible?" and then defers mapping the virtual address space to real storage until it is forced to.

Comment: Your program is not at all typical of a leaking program.  Leaking programs *typically* leak small amounts, and usually don't overtly/obviously have undefined behaviour - and your program (when `malloc()` succeeds) leaks a large amount, and has undefined behaviour on EVERY loop iteration, whether `malloc()` succeeds or fails.  When `malloc()` fails, memory usage of your program (almost certainly - there is never 100% certainty with undefined behaviour in play) stops growing.

Comment: @Chris an infinite loop is only ub when it has no side effects

Comment: @Chris *Just by having an infinite loop, you're in undefined behavior territory* ehr no... it is only undefined behavior if there is no progress (no side effects). The code has a `std::cout` statement so it does make progress. About `malloc` that would be my initial reaction too... but this is really a toy example (so using std::vector or something would be overkill too). new/delete is about as bad as using malloc ;)

Comment: Once your code crashes you are outside of what is defined by the c++ standard. There is simply no reliable portable way to cause a crash. Crashes are caused by undefined behavior, ie anything can happen including: no crash even if you would expect one.

Comment: You misunderstand what your code does std::cout << "addr of p is :" << malloc(kBytes); would output address, yours tries to output string pointed at by p.

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

- `p` has a non-zero value so long as the allocations are successful.
- `p` has a null value once the available memory has been exhausted.

Once the memory has been exhausted, you are assuming that a memory access violation will occur when reading the null pointer value of `p`.

If I create a simpler example of passing a null value to `std::ostream` `operator <<`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        char *psz = nullptr;

        std::cout << "Value of string is: " << psz << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

I get simple output: `Value of string is:`

Although both examples pass a null pointer, there is checking such that `std::ostream::write` just writes an empty string if its `__s` parameter is null.

To induce a memory access violation, try writing to `p` or try a read operation that doesn't involve a function with null-checking.