# block the main thread to wait for its child threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

So I have this class:

```
class foo {
public:
        foo() { };
        void me1() const {
            while(1) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ldock(m);
                std::cout << 0;
            }
        }
        void me2() const {
            while(1) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ldock(m);
                std::cout << 1;
            }
        }
private:
    std::mutex m;
};
```

Now I want to run this two methods in some two different threads, I do it like this:

```
int main() {

    foo myfoo;

    std::thread firstThread(&foo::me1, &myfoo);
    std::thread secondThread(&foo::me2, &myfoo);

    firstThread.detach();
    secondThread.detach();

    //while(1) { }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't want to wait for any of this two methods to finish, they will simultaneously run until the main thread will be killed.

Is it ok to have some kind of infinite-loop at the end of main thread? (like the commented `while(1) {}`).

Or should I call some kinda `sleep` function?

Comment: what do you want main thread to do while the other threads are running?

Comment: If they will simultaneously run until the main thread is killed why don't you just simply wait for them? You will wait for them until they die, if the main thread is killed, both will die anyway. If both of them finish their execution, the main thread has no purpose anymore, so he can die.

Comment: @alexm some stuff that can't be done before that two threads are running.

Comment: It's okay to have the infinite loop at the end but that would *not* achieve what it sounds like you're trying to (it's infinite). Whether or not you should use `sleep` or not seems opinion-based questioning though.

Comment: @SimoneZandara so you are telling me to just `join` them both? but if I join let's say the first one, I will be unable to `join` the second one (because they will run forever). Or I first `detach` one, and then `join` the second one?

Comment: You have an infinite loop in me1 and me2 , there is no need to wait for any of them in main. This is a noQ.

Comment: @MariusMarusanici In your question you say that you don't need to wait for them, when you join two threads, you simply wait for both of them to finish. So if one never ends, your main thread will never end until it's killed, I thought that it was you were asking.

Comment: @g24l If the main thread ends, the subthreads are killed as well so he needs to

Comment: Technically your loop may cause undefined behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3592557/212870

Comment: More importantly, your main thread will be maxing out one core, wasting power and preventing more useful work from running. Any alternative is preferable to a busy wait.

Comment: @SimoneZandara I am just saying that he has no exit condition in his threads.

Comment: Omg , just remove those const specifiers from your function or make the mutex mutable , plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to determine if the two threads have finished your best bet is actually *not* to `detach()` the threads but rather `join()` them before exiting the main thread. That is, you'd kick off both threads and they'll run concurrently and once kicked off you simply `join()` each. Of course, that assumes that the threads would terminate.

Having a `detach()`ed thread effectively means you can never be sure if it has finished. That is generally rarely useful and I consider it a mistake that `detach()` was added to `std::thread`. However, even with `detach()`ed thread you *can* recognize when an objective is achieved without a busy wait. To that end you'd set up suitable variables indicating completion or progress and have them protected by a `std::mutex`. The main thread would then `wait()` on a `std::condition_variable` which gets `notify_once()`ed by the respective thread upon the completion/progress update which would be done in reasonable intervals. Once all threads have indicated that they are done or have achieved a suitable objective the `main()` thread can finish.

Using a timer alone is generally not a good approach. The signalling between threads is typically preferable and tends to create a more responsive system. You can still used a timed version of `wait()` (i.e., `wait_until()` or `wait_for()`), e.g., to alert upon suspecting a somehow hung or timed-out thread.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define an `exit condition` in your `foo::me1()` and `foo::me2()` . If you don't know how to do that, that

```
sleep(/*number of seconds you want your program to run*/ );
```

will do just fine.

If you define a termination clause then the bruteforce would be
to expose something like an atomic:

```
class foo {
public:

std::atomic<int> me1done = false;
std::atomic<int> me2done = false;

        foo() { };
        void me1() {
            while(/* need exit condition here*/) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ldock(m);
                std::cout << 0;
            }
            me1done = true;
        }
        void me2() {
            while(/*need exit condition here*/) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ldock(m);
                std::cout << 1;
            }
            me2done = true;
        }


private:
    std::mutex m;

};
```

and then you can check in main by polling every x-seconds.

```
int main(void)
{
// start your threads and detach

foo myfoo;

std::thread firstThread(&foo::me1, &myfoo);
std::thread secondThread(&foo::me2, &myfoo);

firstThread.detach();
secondThread.detach();

while( not (myfoo.me1done and myfoo.me2done ) )
{
sleep( /* some time */);
}

return 0;
}
```

If you want to be more elaborate you will have to work with [condition variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Answer (score 1):

empty infinite loops as `while(1) { }` are UB.

adding a sleep inside is OK though.

To run infinitely `foo::me1`/`foo::me2`, you have several other choices:

```
int main()
{
    foo myfoo;

    std::thread firstThread(&foo::me1, &myfoo);
    std::thread secondThread(&foo::me2, &myfoo);

    firstThread.join();  // wait infinitely as it never ends.
    secondThread.join(); // and so never reach 
}
```

or simply use main thread to do one work:

```
int main()
{
    foo myfoo;

    std::thread firstThread(&foo::me1, &myfoo);
    myfoo.me2(); // work infinitely as it never ends.

    firstThread.join(); // and so never reach
}
```