# Passing object by reference and Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, pass-by-reference

I have a small problem and wondering if someone can help. I tried to demonstrate my problem in the most simple way possible. I am trying to pass an object by reference to multiple threads. Every thread calls "doSomething" which is a member function that belongs to the object "Example". The "doSomething" function should increment the counter. My gcc version is 4.4.7

**The questions:**

why is the value of the variable "counter" is not incremented although I passed the object by reference to the thread function.

**The code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Exmaple {
    private:
        int counter;

    public:
            Exmaple() { 
            counter = 0;
        }    

        void doSomthing(){
            counter++;
        }

        void print() {
            std::cout << "value from A: " << counter << std::endl;
        }

};

// notice that the object is passed by reference
void thread_task(Exmaple& o) {
    o.doSomthing();
    o.print();
}    

int main()
{
    Exmaple b;
    while (true) {
        std::thread t1(thread_task, b);
        t1.join();
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

**The output:**

```
value from A: 1
value from A: 1
value from A: 1
value from A: 1
value from A: 1
value from A: 1
value from A: 1
value from A: 1
value from A: 1
```

Comment: you need interlocked increment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
while (true) {
    std::thread t1(thread_task, b);
    t1.join();
}
```

Two things you need to know here:

- Use `std::ref` to pass a reference.
- Infinite loop is Undefined Behavior in C++;

Working Example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Exmaple {
    private:
        int counter;

    public:
            Exmaple() { 
            counter = 0;
        }    

        void doSomthing(){
            counter++;
        }

        void print() {
            std::cout << "value from A: " << counter << std::endl;
        }

};

// notice that the object is passed by reference
void thread_task(Exmaple& o) {
    o.doSomthing();
    o.print();
}    

int main()
{
    Exmaple b;
    for(int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::thread t1(thread_task, std::ref(b));
        t1.join();
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
value from A: 1
value from A: 2
value from A: 3
value from A: 4
value from A: 5
value from A: 6
value from A: 7
value from A: 8
value from A: 9
value from A: 10
```

See it [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee2a255098957e42).

*Though going further you should also consider data race*

Comment: You need `atomic_int` or some other means to synchronise.

Comment: I'm curious, I didn't know infinite loops where undefined behavior in C++, what would be the "correct" way to write such a loop?

Comment: @juanchopanza  You are right. Though for the OP's *specific* example I didn't think it necessary to go into that. Added the concern. Thanks

Comment: @ShadowMitia, A correct program in C++ is assumed to terminate, so the correct way to write the loop or any loop is to always test a condition that that will someday exit the loop. Please see the answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x/3593551#3593551) SO thread

Comment: @WhiZTiM this is a very good example, thank you! For completeness, would you mind adding a mutex to the class? Threads should acquire lock, then increment counter, then release it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not very familiar with multithreading, but you're passing `b` by value to the thread, and not by reference. The value of `b` is then passed by reference to `thread_task`, so the value is always 1.

According to [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), you have to write your thread like so to pass objects by reference:

```
std::thread t1(thread_task, std::ref(b));
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in `std::thread t1(thread_task, b)` you pass `b` by value to the constructor of `std::thread` (as you call the constructor here, and not `thread_task` directly). A solution could be to either to wrap `b` by an `std::ref`-object, or change your code to pass a pointer:

```
void thread_task(Exmaple* o) {
    o->doSomthing();
    o->print();
}

int main()
{
    Exmaple b;
    while (true) {
        std::thread t1(thread_task, &b);
        t1.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```