# Invoking function after trying to join a non-terminating thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops, return, infinite-loop

I know that the join method blocks the current thread and waits until the task is done. So how is it possible that I can do something like this:

```
void task()
{
   while(true)
   {
       //do stuff
   }
}

int main()
{
   std::thread t1(task);
   t1.join();
   std::cout << "HELLO" << std::endl;
}
```

and still see "HELLO" after executing this code. Why does this work?

Comment: Basically answered in the question and answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I tried your code and I have an infinite loop using Clang.

Comment: infinite loop with g++

Comment: infinite loop with g++ 5.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should produce an infinite loop.

I cannot reproduce, either on GCC or in Ideone:

[image]

However, if you compile with optimization flags on, then the while loop that does nothing *may* be taken away by the compiler, which explains the behavior. Read more in [Optimizing away a "while(1);" in C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x), provided by Nathan Oliver.

Comment: So does it mean that in proper circumstances it should stuck inside while loop, right?

Comment: Yes @U.Iee, it should produce an infinite loop.

Comment: Ok. I got it. But does it mean that if I want to work with threads I should just invoke join() methods inside main and let's say do nothing else?

Comment: @U.Iee when you need the threads to terminate, you can call `join()` in `main()`.