# Servo only moves once

Tags: c++, stm32, mbed, nucleo

I'm currently working on a school project that uses a servo to bring an arm into a position and then activate a pump with stepper motors. For this I use an STM32 Nucleo L152RE. The problem is that the servo moves to the first position but then the controller stops  and the led ld2 starts blinking and then the controller no longer responds until I reset it. Everything has to be connected correctly because the servo works once.

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include <chrono>

PwmOut servo(PC_7);
InterruptIn s1_pos1(PA_10);
InterruptIn s2_pos2(PA_6);
InterruptIn s3_pos3(PA_1);

PortOut motor(PortC, 0xf00);

int m_state[4] = {0x300, 0x700, 0xc00, 0x900};

Timer timer;

unsigned int const T_periode = 20;

void moveServoToPosition(int position) {
    printf("Moving servo to position %d\r\n", position);
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            servo.pulsewidth_us(500);
            break;
        case 2:
            servo.pulsewidth_us(1500);
            break;
        case 3:
            servo.pulsewidth_us(2500);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void m_pump() {
    printf("Inside m_pump\r\n");
    if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timer.elapsed_time()).count() < 15000) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            motor = m_state[i];
            ThisThread::sleep_for(4ms);
        }
    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
                motor = m_state[i];
                ThisThread::sleep_for(4ms);
            }
        }
        motor = 0x000;
        timer.stop();
        timer.reset();
    }
}

void isr_s1_pos1() {
    printf("ISR s1_pos1 triggered\r\n");
    moveServoToPosition(1);
    m_pump();
}

void isr_s2_pos2() {
    printf("ISR s2_pos2 triggered\r\n");
    moveServoToPosition(2);
    m_pump();
}

void isr_s3_pos3() {
    printf("ISR s3_pos3 triggered\r\n");
    moveServoToPosition(3);
    m_pump();
}

int main() {
    s1_pos1.mode(PullDown);
    s1_pos1.rise(&isr_s1_pos1);

    s2_pos2.mode(PullDown);
    s2_pos2.rise(&isr_s2_pos2);

    s3_pos3.mode(PullDown);
    s3_pos3.rise(&isr_s3_pos3);

    servo.period_ms(T_periode);

    while (true) {
    }
}
```

I tried debugging the controller but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: *I tried debugging the controller but couldn't get it to work.* Couldn't get the debugger to work?

Comment: yes i just don't know how and i coudn't find something useful

Comment: Which `printf` outputs do you see?

Comment: i coudn't see any of them

Comment: I'd start with figuring out the debugger first and then getting back to the code. Once you have a functioning debugger, most bugs become a cakewalk. My usual trick is to stub out the hardware and test the logic out on a PC where the tools are almost always better, but I don't think that's a good option here. Program is very short and very tightly bound to the target.

Comment: An empty unconditional while loop is undefined behaviour

Comment: @AlanBirtles Unfortunately it is necessary

Comment: I have now tested the code individually and each part seems to work individually without any problems.

Comment: @Erazor7 *Unfortunately it is necessary* -- See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x).  I have never used the device you are working with, but shouldn't an API have some sort of "message pump" function or similar to keep going until a shutdown is detected?  Having an empty, infinite `while` loop looks suspicious.

Comment: Are you sure that printf works in ISRs ? Usually that’s not supported. Beware that printf-family functions use quite a lot of stack (and might even use malloc internally).