# How to link vector table from a static library for an embedded project

Tags: c++, c, arm, embedded

I want to make a firmware project for SAMD21 from scratch. The idea behind the project is similar to how [RepRapFirmware](https://www.reprapfirmware.org/) is organized: it is split into "core" static library and main project. The core library contains all low-level stuff like ASF library and custom drivers, and eventually will be ported to other processors. The main project contains higher-level stuff, mostly processor-independent. The "core" lib contains the basic vector table definition and definitions for `Reset_Handler` and `Dummy_Handler`. Other handlers are declared weak and aliased with Dummy. Those which are really needed are supposed to be defined in the main project. I compile the static library, and archive file contains all symbols from vector table. However, when I try to compile the main project and link it against the "core" as a static library, the resulting .elf and .map file don't have any symbols from vector table, excepting for `Reset_Handler`. When I try to compile everything as a single project, the resulting files have all symbols, even those which are not explicitly defined, and the firmware is running normally. I presume that the missing handlers is the root of the problem. Or could it be caused by something else? If the problem is really the missing handlers, how to enforce linking the whole vector table? Copilot doesn't help, all its suggestions are among the ones listed below.

Additional info:

- static lib compilation flags: `-O0 -g3 -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -nostdlib -fno-rtti -fexceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`
- main project compilation flags: `-O0 -g3 -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -nostdlib -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`
- linker flags: `-T/my_path/ATSAMD21J18A.ld -mcpu=cortex-m0plus --specs=nano.specs -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--entry=Reset_Handler -Wl,-Map=/my_path/my_file.map`
- ld script is the standard one from ASF
- also tried without  `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`
- also tried using  `__attribute__((weak, alias("Dummy_Handler"), used))` in handlers' declarations in the library
- tried even this, as proposed by Copilot:

```
extern "C" const DeviceVectors exception_table;

int main() {
    // Use the vector_table symbol somewhere in your code, to prevent the linker
    // from discarding it. This could be a dummy use that doesn't actually affect
    // the behavior of your program.
    if ((int)&exception_table == 0) {
        while(1);
    }

    // Rest of your main program...
}
```

Call stack from debugger:

```
??@0xfffffffe (Unknown Source:0) 
<signal handler called>@0xfffffff9 (Unknown Source:0) 
_sfixed@0x00000000 (Unknown Source:0)
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Linker script

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
SEARCH_DIR(.)

MEMORY
{
  rom      (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00040000
  ram      (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00008000
}

STACK_SIZE = DEFINED(STACK_SIZE) ? STACK_SIZE : DEFINED(__stack_size__) ? __stack_size__ : 0x2000;

/* Section Definitions */
SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sfixed = .;
        KEEP(*(.vectors .vectors.*))
        *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
        *(.glue_7t) *(.glue_7)
        *(.rodata .rodata* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)

        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.init))
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __preinit_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
        __preinit_array_end = .;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        __init_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.init_array))
        __init_array_end = .;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
        KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .ctors))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
        KEEP (*crtend.o(.ctors))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.fini))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        __fini_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.fini_array))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        __fini_array_end = .;

        KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
        KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .dtors))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
        KEEP (*crtend.o(.dtors))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _efixed = .;            /* End of text section */
    } > rom

    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_start = .);
    .ARM.exidx :
    {
      *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    } > rom
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_end = .);

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;

    .relocate : AT (_etext)
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _srelocate = .;
        *(.ramfunc .ramfunc.*);
        *(.data .data.*);
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _erelocate = .;
    } > ram

    .bss (NOLOAD) :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sbss = . ;
        _szero = .;
        *(.bss .bss.*)
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ebss = . ;
        _ezero = .;
    } > ram

    .stack (NOLOAD):
    {
        . = ALIGN(8);
        _sstack = .;
        . = . + STACK_SIZE;
        . = ALIGN(8);
        _stack = .;
    } > ram

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _end = . ;
}
```

Comment: The important bit is missing - the linker script file. You need to tell the linker how to do it. BTW -O0 compilation makes no sense. At least use -Og

Comment: IMO it is a bad design. Keep the low level stuff away from the library.

Comment: @gulpr thank you, but linker script is present: `linker flags: -T/my_path/ATSAMD21J18A.ld ....`, or did you mean the content of that? I'm not yet familiar with syntax of linker scripts, so if you could advise something regarding that, you are totally welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Avoid using AI and other such nonsense/lie generators. Apart from the questionable cast, the code you posted literally says "If the vector table is linked like it should, then hang the program". How does that _not_ affect the rest of the program? Nonsense.

Comment: Btw `while(1);` won't work reliably in C++, since that language allows such loops to finish, leading to undefined behavior in the executable.

Comment: @ArtemPlyusnin the **content** of this file, no its presence.

Comment: @gulpr I updated the initial post with linker script

Answer (score 0):

These things tend to become rather intricate. Misc pointers/advice:

- Indeed you need to ensure that the vector table is linked in the first place. The compiler might not understand that it is used by the program so, either explicitly tell it through the linker script that it *must* link the vector table, or otherwise make it `volatile`, which at least won't do any harm. "Touching" the table like in your code is just a dirty hack which we shouldn't need.
- Additionally, the vector table should also be `const` to guarantee it ends up in flash. So if you for example made it based on an array of function pointers, you'll have something like

  ```
  typedef void isr_t (void);

  volatile isr_t* const vector_table[] = { ... };
  ```

  Note here that this means that pointers themselves are `const` since it was typed on the right side of the `*`. (Additionally you'll have a long list of `__attribute__` goo here too, but you get the basic idea.)
- You need to ensure that the vector table ends up at address 0x0000, which probably means creating a custom section in the linker script and then (on gcc-like compilers) write something like  `__attribute__((section(".vectors")))` to place it there (together with whatever attribute you already use for weak linkage).

  The default ASF linker script very likely assumes that *their* names are used for the vector table and all ISRs, so if you named them anything differently yet didn't change the linker script, then that is the problem.
- The ISRs need to be "thumb functions" so you need to ensure that. I don't remember if `-mthumb` is sufficient or if additional tweaking is needed. You can peek at what addresses they end up at in the .map file or debugger.
- I generally recommend to avoid ASF, it is bloated, buggy and overall not well-written. By all means use their register map and peek at the code in when you write your own drivers, but do write your own drivers. You likely won't need to use every single feature of any given hardware peripheral. Please note that you probably can't use the pre-made register maps when coding in C++ since that language doesn't support union type punning.
- Compile embedded systems with `-ffreestanding`, particularly if you are already using `-nostdlib`. Unfortunately if you are using C++, you cannot declare `void main (void)` as is industry standard, but you have to cook up some work-around instead.

As you might notice from the above, C++ is quite unsuitable for hardware-related programming. Check out [Is there something that I can do in C but I can't do in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75171239/584518) Consider porting to C which has better support for microcontroller programming.

Comment: thanks, I updated my initial post with linker script. It does include .vectors section, and the table is declared in .c file as `__attribute__((section(".vectors"))) const DeviceVectors exception_table = {}`. I also tried other points, but nothing helped

Comment: @ArtemPlyusnin How is the type `DeviceVectors` defined? Also I take it that `= {}` is just pseudo code and the real program has a list of functions there instead?

Comment: thank you for all the comments. I fixed the problem: in original RepRapFirmware code, which I used as reference, the linkage is provided by definition of a global variable in the .c file, containing the vector table. I did the same trick and everything works now. Regarding the DeviceVectors definition - it is similar to how it is done in RepRapFirmware (but for different processors) and in Arduino core for SAMD21